# Load a component with Link, which then loads data based on selected item

Tags: reactjs

I am making a basic site, as a learning project, and hit a problem. My 'oages' are loaded via `Link`s. My routes are all setup in my app.jsx like this.

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <div>
            <Navbar />
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
            <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
            <Route path="/clients" component={Clients} />
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I've hit my first scenario where a user clicks an item in a list, and I need to load the details of that selected item. So I need to pass props in my `<Link...>` so that the component I load knows what Id was selected.

Is this possible? Or should I start investing time in learning about the whole new `context` ability of React. What would the pattern be? Put a value into the context, then `<Link...>` to open the component, which would then read from the Context to get the `SelectedId`? At the moment, I just need to pass the id of the selected item, and load a new component.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways I can think of you could do that without involving other libraries or local/session storage or cookies.

1. Use [react context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) as you suggested.
2. [lift the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)
   . Which means your main component would keep and update the id and pass it to components:

   ```
     ...
     <Route
       exact
       path="/"
       render={props => (
         <Home
           {...props}
           id={this.state.id}
           onUpdateId={this.handleUpdateId}
         />
       )}
     />
     <Route
       path="/login"
       render={props => (
         <Login
           {...props}
           id={this.state.id}
           onUpdateId={this.handleUpdateId}
         />
       )}
     />
     ...
   ```
3. Use react-router [location state](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location).

This would involve creating custom `Link` component or programmatically redirecting with `history` prop. Check out the [auth workflow](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) example.

Comment: Brilliant @tomasz. Would you recommend any? The custom component sounds good. But for learning, so would Context. But that sounds pretty complex for a beginner.

Comment: @Craig I would recommend lifting the state up. That's because this technique will serve you many more times as it closer to how you should [think in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-4-identify-where-your-state-should-live).

Comment: lifting the state seems like the right thing to do. But would it be right in an example where I show a list of Clients... and then when the user selects a row, I load a whole new component, which shows an edit screen for the client. That new component would have it's own Api, which would be getting a complex model for the client. Does 'List the State' mean my List view component actually holds all the data, and passes the 'Client' object to the Edit component on click?